# Proof about normal subgroups of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of G. Show $M \cap N$ is a normal subgroup of G

Approach:

Case 1 $x \in M \cap N$

if $x\in M \cap N$ then clearly $x(M \cap N)=(M \cap N)x$

Case 2 $x \notin M \cap N$

Let $y \in M \cap N$, so $y \in M$ and $y \in N$ which implies $xy=yx$ because $M$ and $N$ are normal, so $x(M \cap N)=(M \cap N)x$

how does that look?

Comment: Show $M \cap N$ is what?

Comment: You seem to suffer from the misunderstanding that $xM=Mx$ implies that $xy=yx$ for all $y\in M$. That's not what it means. $xM=Mx$ means for all $y\in M$ there exists a $z\in M$ such that $xy=zx$.

Comment: ok, but z can also be y right?, but yes, I agree with your definition, so $xy=zx$ for some $z \in M$ and $xy=tx$ for some $t \in M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $M\cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, you must show that every element $g\in G$ satisfies $g(M\cap N)g^{-1}\subseteq M\cap N$. In fact, given $x\in M\cap N$ and $g\in G$, since $M$ and $N$ are normal in $G$, then $$gxg^{-1}\in M \ \ \mbox{and}\ \ gxg^{-1}\in N$$ so $gxg^{-1}\in M\cap N$. Since $x$ and $g$ are arbitrary, it follows that $M\cap N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Nice, I was trying to show the other direction, but it looks too complicated hence it involves too many variables.

Comment: I friended you on facebook by the way